# Imprimir desde PHP con coordenadas

Tags: php, imprimir, impresora

Buen día desarrolladores, estoy desarrollando algo en **PHP**, pero necesito saber si hay alguna manera de imprimir con coordenadas, yo tengo experiencia en c# con las impresiones y ahí hay una manera de hacerlo por medio de valores en x - y, pero buscando como hacerlo en php no he logrado hallar mucho, solo como mandar a imprimir desde el navegador creando un documento **HTML** pero no es lo que requiero, ya que necesito poder imprimir con una plantilla de recibos.

¿Como puedo realizar la impresión?

Comment: pues es imprimir ciertos datos para generar un reporte pero sobre hojas que ya tienen un formato, entonces los datos deberían estar colocados en los espacios de la hoja... los datos los obtengo mediante post

Comment: @AlfredoPaz con PHP se pueden hacer muchas cosas no orientadas a la web, se pueden [procesar y editar imágenes](http://php.net/manual/es/refs.utilspec.image.php), [manipular audio](http://php.net/manual/es/refs.utilspec.audio.php), o [controlar la impresora](http://php.net/manual/fa/ref.printer.php) entre otras cosas.

Comment: @josemarquez mira las funciones de impresora del enlace de arriba, en concreto te puede interesar [`printer_draw_text`](http://php.net/manual/fa/function.printer-draw-text.php) que te permite escribir texto en la posición indicada. Si añades más detalle a tu pregunta (¿cómo estás imprimiendo las hojas ahora mismo?¿qué has intentado?¿con qué problemas te estás encontrando?) y algo de código, podríamos ayudarte mejor y darte una respuesta más concreta. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP tiene una extensión que permite imprimir a una impresora conectada al servidor usando las [funciones de impresión](http://php.net/manual/fa/ref.printer.php) (tristemente la documentación no está disponible en español y la extensión es sólo para Windows).

Lo más difícil de esta extensión es hacerla funcionar (yo lo intenté en el pasado con WampServer y no lo conseguí), puedes encontrar los ficheros necesarios en la [página oficial de PHP](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/printer/0.1.0-dev/) e instrucciones sobre cómo instalarlos [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15338132/3695983) (aunque la idea básica es copiar el DLL a la carpeta de extensiones de PHP y activarla en php.ini).

Una vez que tengas la extensión instalada y corriendo, puedes usar el método [`printer_draw_text`](http://php.net/manual/fa/function.printer-draw-text.php) para poner texto en las coordenadas especificadas (traducción mía):

> **Descripción**
>
> ```
> void printer_draw_text ( resource $printer_handle , string $text , int $x , int $y )
> ```
>
> La función dibuja texto en la posición x,y usando la fuente seleccionada.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> printer_handle
>   printer_handle debe ser un controlador válido para una impresora.
>
> text
>   El texto a escribir.
>
> x
>   x es la coordenada x de la posición.
>
> y
>   y es la coordenada y de la posición.

---

Y aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo se usa sacado de esa misma página de php.net (he renombrado algunas variables para que sea más fácil de seguir y añadido comentarios para facilitar la comprensión):

```
<?php
// conectamos a la impresora y comenzamos un documento de impresión
$controlador = printer_open();
printer_start_doc($controlador, "Mi Documento");
printer_start_page($controlador);

// seleccionamos una fuente Arial con 72x48 pixels de alto x ancho y sin negrita
$fuente = printer_create_font("Arial", 72, 48, 400, false, false, false, 0);
printer_select_font($controlador, $fuente);

// escribimos el texto "Test" en la posición 10,10 de la página
printer_draw_text($controlador, "Test", 10, 10);
printer_delete_font($fuente);

// finalizamos el documento y cerramos la conexión con la impresora
printer_end_page($controlador);
printer_end_doc($controlador);
printer_close($controlador);
?>
```